# Add data from array to table cell

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add value from my NSMutableArray to table cell. When I do that the cells are empty. But if I print what is in the array it is printing the data. I just can't get data on the cell.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : FinalTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! FinalTableViewCell
        cell.headingLabel!.text = self.headingArray[indexPath.row] as String
        var value: String = headingArray[indexPath.row] as String
        println(value)

        println(self.finalModelData.valueForKey(value))

        cell.informationLabel!.text = self.finalModelData.valueForKey(value) as? String

        return cell

    }
```

Comment: Is the code you have displayed being called (ie do you get the print statements). Is your table actually being displayed (ie check constraints,set a different background colour and make sure it shows up)

Comment: I do get the print statements to print. Table is being displayed, and I have 2 labels for each row, so i first one is being displayed but the informationLabel is not printing. and to check that the informationLabel is working correctly I simply printed Name there and it showed up.

Comment: You might want to check if you have correctly set up all the outlets being used in the cell. Can you confirm that once?

Comment: Yes, I directly said cell.informationLabel!.text = "Name" and It prints name.